# How to transcode Windows-1251 to UTF-8?

Tags: php, windows, utf-8, cp1251

How to transcode Windows-1251 to UTF-8?

Will such function do it?

```
function win_to_utf($s) 
{ 
for($i=0, $m=strlen($s); $i<$m; $i++) 
{ 
$c=ord($s[$i]); 
if ($c<=127) 
{$t.=chr($c); continue; } 
if ($c>=192 && $c<=207) 
{$t.=chr(208).chr($c-48); continue; } 
if ($c>=208 && $c<=239) 
{$t.=chr(208).chr($c-48); continue; } 
if ($c>=240 && $c<=255) 
{$t.=chr(209).chr($c-112); continue; } 
if ($c==184) { $t.=chr(209).chr(209); 
continue; }; 
if ($c==168) { $t.=chr(208).chr(129); 
continue; }; 
} 
return $t; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conversion doesn't look correct. Why don't you use iconv or mbstring?

```
$utf8 = iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $ansi);
```

Answer (score 1):

Php.net has a couple of [helpful examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.convert-cyr-string.php).